# Comparing two SQL scripts and getting alter script

Tags: .net, sql, windows, visual-studio, smo

I have two  different Database (say source and target) consisting of 1 Table (Customer, Columns - ID/Name) in both.  Suppose I modify the table in source table and get the updated script and do a comparison with the target table, how can I get the alter script out of them using only **SMO object**.

Is there any way of comparing two script and get the alter script.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the script comparison.

But if your goal is to compare two existing tables (say production vs dev SQL), you should check out Redgate's SQLCompare. It can generate the change scripts, or even better, apply the changes directly. Pretty sweet product IMO

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare

Comment: Thank you Mellodev for your quick response. But I don't want to use any tool other than SMO.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, there is a Data menu where you can execute a Schema Compare of two data source defined. The resulting script could be exported and used-

I'm not sure if this functionality is present in lesser capable versions of Visual Studio

Comment: Thank you Steve for your kind response. I tried this earlier what you have suggested and its pretty decent. But I want to achieve this using the SMO and through code.